# Trouble importing RootCA certificate authority into Chromium in Raspbian OS

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi3

I am setting up the Raspberry PI 3B+ device and running on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch). I am trying to import the company Root certificate to access intranet sites in Raspberry PI. I have understood that Chromium does not use the default store and instead it uses nssdb. Tried adding the cert (in all formats .cer, .pem, .crt) using the certutil command as below.

certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n certificate nickname -i certificate path/filename

I could also able to list the certificate from the nssdb and also could see the details. However, Chromium does not still recognize the certificate / the certificate are not being referenced. In the end, I still see the intranet sites are listed as "Not secure" at the left side of the address bar. if you have experienced similar issues and have a fix then do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer as I was trying to import the certificate with the Root and was testing with a different user. Meaning, For all the users (whoever logged into Pi) should have the certificate imported. Tried to import the cert to the user who is logging in (not using the root) using the crontab through a startup script. After this the certificate is imported successfully in the SSL option in Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium on Raspbian OS won't make use of the system's trusted CA store like Google's Chrome will. You need to import the CAs into Chromium specifically, in the same fashion you need to do this for Mozilla's NSS with Firefox or Thunderbird.

To do this on Chromium version 92:

1. Open **Settings**.
2. Click **Privacy and security** in the side bar.
3. Click **Security**.
4. Scroll down to **Manage certificates** near the bottom, click it.
5. Select the **Authorities** tab.
6. Click **Import**.
7. Choose your CA files you want Chromium to trust.
8. Tick **Trust this certificate for identifying websites**, or all 3 options if you like, then click **OK**.

Your CA will now be trusted in Chromium. Restarting the application is not required, just refreshing tabs will do.